# How do I decide if Domain-Driven Design would be applicable to this project?

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, web-applications

I'm at the stage where I'm taking my MVP app and trying to refactor and structure it in a way that it is maintainable and extendible. I'm new to software architecture or design so I'm having early struggles deciding what pattern would suit best my application.

How do I go about and investigate if ***Domain Driven Design pattern (DDD)*** be appropriate here considering that I have distinct domain (tournament registration) and a lot of complexity in terms of generating brackets and interacting with multiple services?

The web app runs on Nuxt (using Vue.js and Express) and it communicates with services through network calls.

**Here is a list of things that I have**

- Bracket API – responsible for generating bracket, fetching matchups, getting current state of the bracket, updating byes, updating players in the bracket etc.
- Tournament API – responsible for putting users into tournaments, starting tournaments, ending them and rewarding players
- Reward API – picks appropriate reward based on tournament place and sends rewards to users
- Cognito API – user accounts
- PostgreSQL to store users, tournaments, matchups, rewards, etc.
- FTPService – responsible for taking game config files and uploading it onto the game server
- FileService – builds JSON files from POCOs
- CloudHostingService - using ***Digital Ocean*** as a service that allows me to interact with digital ocean API; creating droplets, shutting them off, accessing droplet IPs, etc.
- PaymentService - using ***Stripe API*** to initialize payments, utilizing hooks to listen for payment events. Upon successful payments, players are put into a tournament
- GameService - responds to game call-backs. I’m using ***CounterStrike*** as a game of choice and this service will respond to in-game call-backs such as; round start, game end, score changed, etc. which I am using to update the web UI
- NotificationService - utilizes ***Discord API*** and I’m using it for bot development responsible for sending notifications to discord channels

Any help will be extremely appreciated.

Thanks,
Patrick.

Comment: I did not downvote, but it seems you are putting a ton of technical information into the text which is most probably irrelevant to the question. This gives me the impression that you haven't informed yourself enough of what DDD is about, which should be the prerequisite before evaluating this approach (which is, by the way, not a pattern, at least not in the sense how the term pattern is usually used by the community here).

Comment: DDD is not a pattern. It is a way to create a place in your code that is free of infrastructure jargon that uses the vocabulary of your domain experts.  So the question is if your project would benefit from that. Do you have domain experts who aren’t coders?